# On a 16-bit microprocessor, should I be using datatype short instead of int?

Tags: c, types, char, int, short

I've read that using `short` vs `int` is actually creating an inefficiency for the compiler in that it needs to use the `int` datatype regardless because of C integer promotion.  Is this true for 16-bit microprocessors?

Another question: If I have an array of 1s and 0s, is it most efficient to use `uint8_t` or the `unsigned char` in this 16-bit microprocessor?  Or is there still an issue with it being converted back to int..

Please help me clear up this muddy issue in my mind.  Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us what particular 16-bit microprocessor you're talking about. There are at least many dozens of potential candidates, why not just tell us who makes it and what its model number is.

Comment: The exact size of an intergral type is implementation defined - the compiler can decide depending on the target platform. I doubt it would be stupid enough to use a size for `int` that the processor doesn't support natively - especially since `int` is inofficially supposed to be the target's native word size. Check `sizeof int` on the compiler in question on the target in question.

Comment: @jer: I'm working on a Analog Device Blackfin if that helps.

Comment: From `sizeof(int)`, I get 4.  With `sizeof(short)`, I get 2.  I kinda expected the `sizeof(int)` to be 2 as well... Should I still be using int?  Still don't make total sense to me.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't confuse C Implementation with microprocessor. The former can make its types virtually any size, even if the CPU could not natively handle it.

Comment: I don't know about Blackfin's compiler but some compilers for embedded system do have an option to disable C promotion rules compliance for faster code execution because 8-bit or 16-bit maths does not always need to promote to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Blackfin it is probably not a simple answer whether 32 or 16 bit types will generate higher performance generally since it supports 16, 32 and 64-bit instructions, and has two 16 bit MACs.  It will depend on the operations, but I suggest that you trust your compiler optimiser to make such decisions, it knows more about the processor's instruction timing and scheduling than you probably care to.

That said it may be that in your compiler int and short are the same size in any case.  Consult the documentation, ot test with `sizeof`  , or look in the `limits.h` header for numeric ranges that will infer the widths or the various types.

If you truly want to restrict data type size use the `stdint.h` types such as `int16_t`.

`stdint.h` also defines [fastest minimum-width integer types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#Fastest_minimum-width_integer_types) such as `int_fast16_t`, this will guarantee a minimum width, but will use a larger type if it will be faster on your target.  This is the probably the most portable way of solving your problem, but it relies on the implementer to have made good decisions about the appropriate types to use.  On most architectures it makes little or no difference, but on RISC and DSP architectures that may not be the case.  It may also not be the case that a particular size is fastest in all circumstances, and that is probably especially true in the case of Blackfin.

In some cases (where large amounts of data are transferred to an from external memory), the fastest size is likely to be one that matches the data bus width.

Answer (score 5):

1. Is it really an issue? On most 16 bit systems I've heard of, `int` and `short` end up being the same size (16 bits), so there shouldn't really be a difference in practice.
2. If `uint8_t` exists on a system, it's going to be synonymous with `unsigned char`. `unsigned char` will be the smallest unsigned type avaliable on the system. If it's any more than 8 bits, there will be no `uint8_t`. If it's less than 8 bits, then it's violating the standard. There will be no efficiency difference since one has to be defined in terms of the other.

Lastly, do you really need to worry about these kind of microscopic differences? If you do you'll need to peek at the assembly output or (more likely) profile and see which one is faster.

Answer (score 2):

On a 16-bit or larger processor, if you don't care how much storage things will take, use 'int' instead of 'short' or 'signed char'.  If you don't care about storage requirements or wrapping behavior, use 'unsigned int' instead of 'unsigned short' or 'unsigned char'.  On an 8-bit processor, 'char' types may be faster than 'int', but on 16-bit and larger processors where 16-bit math is faster than 32-bit math, 'int' is likely to be 16 bits so there's no need to use 'short' or 'char' for speed.

BTW, on some processors, 'unsigned short' is much slower than 'unsigned int', because the C standard requires that operations on unsigned types 'wrap'.  If unsigned short variable "foo" is stored in a register, a typical ARM compiler generating code for "foo+=1;" would generate one instruction to do the increment, and two instructions to truncate the value to 65535 [BTW, an optimizing compiler that noticed that 'foo' could never exceed 65536 could shave an instruction, but I don't know if any real compilers would].  The signed 'short' would not have to be slower than 'signed int', since no truncation is mandated by the standard; I'm not sure whether any compilers would skip the truncation for signed types, though.

Comment: IMO your discussion about unsigned doesn't make sense. You can just do you can just doing your addition, subtraction, multiplication using the full register and only do the masking to 65535 when you need to store the result (that's a nice property of modulo arithmetic). Actually `short` and `char` are just "storage" types because they're automatically converted to `int` in an expression... for example `unsigned char x=255; int y = x+1;' will assign 256 to `y` even if a char is 8 bit and an int is 16, as no wrapping will happen during the addition.

Comment: A bit confused with wrapping and truncation; they are not the same.  I just examined the output of an ARM compiler (ARM's own armcc) using ARM mode (as opposed to Thumb) on an ARM7TDMI target, and your assertions do not hold up.

Comment: @6502: If an unsigned short variable is held in a register, then compliance with the spec will require that the register be truncated to an unsigned short.  Saying "intval = ushortval + 1;" would require that the value not be truncated, but "ushortval +=1; intval = ushortval;" would require truncation, as would "if (!++ushortval) ...".

Comment: @Clifford: What did you try and what was the result?  Note that intermediate computations in registers don't have to be truncated to ushort (indeed they can't be in any case that would matter) but assignments to variables which happen to have been optimized to registers must be truncated if unsigned.  Signed registers don't have to be truncated, but I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers do it anyway.

Comment: @supercat:  What I tried and the result are not easy to report in a comment block.  I declared a volatile short integer variable, then did foo+=1 as you suggested, and then assigned that to a second static volatile short.  I used signed shorts since you did not specify and the original post specified signed in any case.  They were volatile to prevent the compiler making assumptions about stored values. The static declaration was to force memory storage rather than a register. I probably don't care enough to investigate further.

Comment: @Clifford: The compiler isn't required to do anything special with signed shorts; unsigned shorts, however, must 'wrap'.  Try "int test(void) {unsigned short foo,bar; foo = 65535; foo++; bar = foo; if (bar != 0) bar++; return bar;}"  I'm pretty sure you'll see integer-truncation code there; I'd be curious how smartly the compiler generates it.

Answer (score 0):

I make a point of having a block that looks like this in projects that rely on byte sizes:

```
typedef uint8 char
typedef uint16 short
typedef uint32 long
```

For whatever datatypes are appropriate.

Any conversion issues should be figured out at compile time. Those will be cpu and compiler dependent.

Of course adding 2 32-bit numbers on a 16-bit CPU will entail some finangling by the compiler. There can also be amusing things when you dink with loading from memory, depending on memory word width and whether you can load from any address, or if bytes have to be loaded from a given boundary

In `short`, YMMV, and optimize after profiling.

Comment: Instead of rolling your own datatypes, simply `#include <stdint.h>` to get `uint8_t`, `uint32_t`, etc.  That way, you won't have to write your own typedefs for every platform, as those data types are defined (by the C99 standard) to be the specified length on all conforming implementations.

Comment: @bta: Sure, if you can rely on using C99-conformant compilers! But yeah, that's a 'best practice' if you can.

Comment: <stdint.h> is merely a header file implementation, you do not need a C99 compiler; you can create your own that is C99 compatible for any compiler that does not provide it.  That will save you having to create these types for *all* compilers you might ever use.